# Most Viewed Product not updated

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I am using below code for the most viewed products at home page, but My client keep complaining that these products were not updating.

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addUrlRewrite()
    ->addTaxPercents()          
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image')) //edit to suit tastes
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->addViewsCount();  

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
    $products->setPageSize($this->getConfig('qty'))->setCurPage(1);
```

Please check and let me know what is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This. It's working on my flat catalog

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
              ->addViewsCount();
if (Mage::helper('catalog/product_flat')->isEnabled()) {

$collection->getSelect()->joinInner(array('e2' => 'catalog_product_flat_'.$storeId), 'e2.entity_id = e.entity_id');
}
```